# Map Oracle DB Table with no primary but with unique index

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, orm, mapping

We have Oracle database which cannot modify in any way.
Most of the tables are generic and...they don't have primary key.
ORM (EF) Won't map a table without a primary key.

But I see that a table has Unique Index.

Can I map that table with EF 6 via the Unique Index.

Comment: Which approach do you use: code first or database first?

Comment: Database first.

Answer (score 1):

Set primary key in silence mode:

```
public class MyContext: DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Car>()
            .HasKey(c => new { c.State, c.LicensePlate });
    }
}
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations

Comment: Thank you.
The case was that we are not able to map the table, therefore "Car" doesn't exist, hence can't use this code: Entity<Car>...

Comment: So You currently don't have the model (POCO, entity) class?

Comment: Correct, that is what I was trying to do - to map it.

Comment: Have You DbContext or You need everythig?

Comment: Yes, I have DbContext and other objects are mapped. This is no longer an issue, the system is completed. I can't remember exactly, but I think I just created a DTO myself and manually populated it. No worries, thanks for your help.